# Why do I keep losing weapons in GTA V online when I save?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

So a regular session will go like this:
- log in to the multiplayer world and examine my weak arsenal of 3 different pistols + 2 shotties + a baseball bat.
- start a gang war or survival mission and pick up some decent guns. Usually end up with Carbine Rifle + SMG + Micro SMG.
- enjoy playing GTAV online for a while.
- quit back to story mode to save, either by selecting Michael, Trevor or Francis - or by selecting the option in the Online menu.
- start another online session the next day - aaaand back to step 1. Where is my Carbine/SMG/etc??????

I initially supposed this was due to me not saving correctly, and then I thought maybe it was some undocumented "feature" where you can't keep weapons until you get to a certain level. I can't find any mention of such a thing in the [Rockstar Social Club GTA online guide](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/tutorials). I found this [link](http://au.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/List_of_GTA_Online_Rank_Unlocks) which supposedly lists when weapons get unlocked, but I'm level 43 and I'm still stuck with a Combat Pistol as my best default weapon.

How do I keep my weapons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are only allowed to keep weapons you have purchased in Ammunation. Weapons you have picked up during missions etc are only available until you log off from GTA Online.

You also lose the weapons if you die or change session.

Comment: I purchased some add-ons for my Combat Pistol, but I don't recall buying the 2 shotguns I have by default?   I've also purchased a sniper rifle before and had it disappear, but maybe that was when the Rockstar servers went down (usually every 2nd session for me it seems)

Comment: Confirmed when I buy something and it stays in my inventory now when I reload. I must have lost connection to the servers before it saved when I tried this before. Would be nice if Rockstar told you this kind of info.

Answer (score -1):

Only purchased guns can be saved.

Comment: Can you provide some source for this information?

Answer (score -2):

When you die you start to lose your ammunition and then you lose your guns after you have lost all of your ammunition.

Comment: This is not correct. Also this question is 1 year old.